# How can I access React state in my eventHandler?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-hooks, react-leaflet, use-state

This is my state:

```
const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([])
```

I initialise a Leaflet map in a useEffect hook. It has a `click` eventHandler.

```
useEffect(() => {
    map.current = Leaflet.map('mapid').setView([46.378333, 13.836667], 12)
    .
    .
    .
    map.current.on('click', onMapClick)
}, []
```

Inside that `onMapClick` I create a marker on the map and add it to the state:

```
const onMapClick = useCallback((event) => {
    console.log('onMapClick markers', markers)
    const marker = Leaflet.marker(event.latlng, {
        draggable: true,
        icon: Leaflet.divIcon({
            html: markers.length + 1,
            className: 'marker-text',
        }),
    }).addTo(map.current).on('move', onMarkerMove)

    setMarkers((existingMarkers) => [ ...existingMarkers, marker])
}, [markers, onMarkerMove])
```

But I would also like to access the `markers` state here. But I can't read `markers` here. It's always the initial state. I tried to call `onMapClick` via a onClick handler of a button. There I can read `markers`. Why can't I read `markers` if the original event starts at the map? How can I read the state variables inside `onMapClick`?

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-mendel-r58zp?file=/src/map4.js
When you click in the map and have a look at the console you see that the `markers` array in `onMapClick` stays empty while it gets filled in the `useEffect` that listens for `markers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React state is asynchronous and it won't immediately guarantee you to give you the new state, as for your question **Why can't I read markers if the original event starts at the map** its an asynchronous nature and the fact that state values are used by functions based on their current closures and state updates will reflect in the next re-render by which the existing closures are not affected but new ones are created, this problem you wont face on class components as you have **this** instance in it, which has global scope.

As a developing a component , we should make sure the components are controlled from where you are invoking it, instead of function closures dealing with state , it will re-render every time state changes . Your solution is viable you should pass a value whatever event or action you pass to a function, when its required.

Edit:- its Simple just pass params or deps to useEffect and wrap your callback inside, for your case it would be

```
useEffect(() => {
    map.current = Leaflet.map('mapid').setView([46.378333, 13.836667], 12)
    .
    .
    .
    map.current.on('click',()=> onMapClick(markers)) //pass latest change
}, [markers] // when your state changes it will call this again
```

for more info check this one out https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/  , it will help you for longer term !!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that React state is asynchronous but I don't really know how I can refactor my solution so that the eventHandler which the map event calls can access the state.

Answer (score 3):

Long one but you'll understand why this is happening and the better fixes. Closures are especially an issue (also hard to understand), mostly when we set **click handlers which are dependent on the state**, if the handler function with the new scope is not re-attached to the click event, then closures remain un-updated and hence the **stale state remains in the click handler function**.

If you understand it perfectly in your component, `useCallback` is returning a new reference to the updated function i.e `onMapClick` **having your updated markers ( the state)** in its scope, but since you are setting the 'click' handler only in the beginning when the component is mounted, the click handler remains un-updated since you've put a check `if(! map.current)`, which prevents any new handler to be attached on the map.

```
// in sandbox map.js line 40
  useEffect(() => {
    // this is the issue, only true when component is initialized
    if (! map.current) {
      map.current = Leaflet.map("mapid4").setView([46.378333, 13.836667], 12);
      Leaflet.tileLayer({ ....}).addTo(map.current);
      // we must update this since onMapClick was updated
      // but you're preventing this from happening using the if statement
      map.current.on("click", onMapClick);
    }

  }, [onMapClick]);
```

Now I tried moving `map.current.on("click", onMapClick);` out of the `if` block, but there's an issue,  Leaflets instead of replacing the click handler with the new function, it [adds another event handler](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-other-methods) ( basically stacking event handlers ), so we must remove the old one before adding the new one, otherwise we will end up adding multiple handlers each time `onMapClick` is updated. For which we have the `off()` function.

Here's the updated code

```
// in sandbox map.js line 40
useEffect(() => {
  // this is the issue, only true when component is initialized
  if (!map.current) {
    map.current = Leaflet.map("mapid4").setView([46.378333, 13.836667], 12);
    Leaflet.tileLayer({ ....
    }).addTo(map.current);
  }

  // remove out of the condition block
  // remove any stale click handlers and add the updated onMapClick handler
  map.current.off('click').on("click", onMapClick);

}, [onMapClick]);
```

This is the link to the updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-driscoll-6tj65?file=/src/map4.js) which is working just fine.

Now there's another Idea to solve it without replacing click handler each time. i.e some globals, which I believe is not really too bad.

For this add `globalMarkers` outside but above your component and update it each time.

```
let updatedMarkers = [];

const Map4 = () => {
  let map = useRef(null);
  let path = useRef({});
  updatedMarkers =  markers; // update this variable each and every time with the new markers value
  ......

  const onMapClick = useCallback((event) => {
   console.log('onMapClick markers', markers)
   const marker = Leaflet.marker(event.latlng, {
      draggable: true,
      icon: Leaflet.divIcon({
        // use updatedMarkers here
        html: updatedMarkers.length + 1,
        className: 'marker-text',
      }),
    }).addTo(map.current).on('move', onMarkerMove)

    setMarkers((existingMarkers) => [ ...existingMarkers, marker])
  }, [markers, onMarkerMove])
 .....

} // component end
```

And this one works perfectly too, Link to the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-wildflower-xuznz?file=/src/map4.js:161-257) with this code. This one works faster.

And lastly, the above solution of passing it as a param is okay too! I prefer the one with updated `if` block since it's easy to modify and you get the logic behind it.